# How To Add Total to Cacti Graph

Tags: cacti

I have created the following graph in Cacti: http://i43.tinypic.com/34y2nfo.png

I have created an aggregate of twenty graphs, this is great, it's stacked them on top of each other showing the total value with each contributing graph entry below.

All I want at the very bottom of the graph is a line with totals of the current, average and max values; but I'm pulling my hair out trying to make it happen? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit the graph template this graph uses (from the "Graph Templates" page)-

1. remove the comments from legend that are already there that you don't want.
2. add an entry with the following info

   - data source: none
   - color: your choice, useless
   - opacity: greyed out
   - graph item type: gprint
   - consolidation function: average
   - CDEF Function: total all data sources
   - Value: blank
   - Gprint type: normal
   - text format: total amount
   - insert hard return: checked

You can tweak some of those settings like the **consolidation function** (*in fact, to get the min, max, and avg numbers you want you'll need to create a total of three of these, one with each of these selections*), **gprint type**, **text format**, and **insert hard return**. You can also move it up or down on the legend in relation to whatever you haven't deleted from the first major step.